# How can I search using PHP code suburbs name and post code together

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell me, I am going to search suburbs name and post code together. My PHP code will work only following combinations.
(more details Suburb Name: Rose Bay, Post code 2029)
can search

- rosebay2029
- 2029rosebay

can't search

- rose bay2029
- rosebay 2029
- rose bay 2029
- ROSE-BAY 2029
- 2029 rosebay
- 2029 rose bay
- 2029rose bay

Could you please tell me how do I improve my PHP code all combination(9) search.

```html
$serchkey = isset($_POST['search'])? $_POST['search'] : "0000  map";
$value=explode(" ",$serchkey);
$suburbsname= urlencode(str_replace("-","",$value[0]));
$postcode = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $suburbsname);
$suburbs = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/','', $suburbsname);
$result = mb_substr($suburbs, 0, 4); // I need to display suburbs name first 4 letters
$geturlcontent = "http://myurl/Data?pcode=".$postcode."&SuburbName=".$result;    
echo $suburbsname."<br>";
echo $suburbs."<br>";
echo $postcode."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will remove all non alpha-numeric chars and look for Suburb and Post Code in string :

```
function searchFunction($searchKey){
    $searchKey = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i', '', $searchKey);
    $suburbs = "";
    $postCode = "";
    $lastCharString = false;
    $numericCount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<strlen($searchKey); $i++){
        $isNumeric = is_numeric($searchKey[$i]);
        if($lastCharString && $isNumeric && $numericCount > 0){
            return false; // Mixed search string like ro0sebay20
        }
        if(!$isNumeric){
            $suburbs.=$searchKey[$i];
            $lastCharString = true;
        }else{
            $numericCount++;
            $lastCharString = false;
            $postCode.=$searchKey[$i];
        }
    }
    return array( 'suburbs' => $suburbs, 'postCode' => $postCode );
}
```

You can see test results by :

```
var_dump(searchFunction("rose bay2029")); // suburbs = rosebay, postCode = 2029
var_dump(searchFunction("000-0 map")); // suburbs = map , postCode = 0000 
var_dump(searchFunction("0000 ma2p")); // false
```

Comment: please tell me how do I pass values to $geturlcontent = "http://myurl/Data?pcode=".$postcode."&SuburbName=".$suburbs ; ?

Comment: You can do it like 

$result = searchFunction("rosebay2029");
if(!result){
$returnedFromUrl = file_get_contents("yoururl/?suburb=".$result["suburbs"]."&postCode=".$result["postCode"]);
}else{
// Search string error
}

Comment: Are there any issue this call function only go else print only error. $result = searchFunction();
 if(!result)
 { 
 $returnedFromUrl = file_get_contents("yoururl/?pcode=".$result["po‌​stCode"]."&SuburbName=".$result["suburbs"]); 
 
 
echo $returnedFromUrl."<br>";
echo $result["suburbs"]."<br>";
echo $returnedFromUrl;
 }
 else
 
 {

 // Search string error 

echo $returnedFromUrl;
 echo "Error";
 }

Comment: Please tell me how do I pass value to $returnedFromUrl = file_get_contents("yoururl/?pcode=".$result["po‌​stCode"]."&SuburbName=".$result["suburbs"]);?

Comment: Hi Erol, Is your function working correctly? because I added below echo line to else block echo $result["po‌​stCode"]."<br>";
echo $result["suburbs"]; Only print Suburb name, post code missing. Why was that?

Comment: I tested it in a local machine and phpfiddle it should work correctly sir

Comment: Are any issue with this code? $result = searchFunction();
 if(!result)
 { 
 $returnedFromUrl = file_get_contents("yoururl/?pcode=".$result["po‌​stCode"]."&SuburbName=".$result["suburbs"]); 
 

 }
 else
 
 {

 // Search string error 

echo $returnedFromUrl;
 echo "Error";
 }

Comment: $result = searchFunction($suburbs,$postCode); function call is Array(echo $result), do you know how read array in php?

Comment: If search was succesful it returns an array, if not it returns false. You can read it easily like : 

    $result = searchFunction($input);  echo $result['suburbs'];

Comment: search was successful but only empty value echo $result['suburbs'];

Comment: Can you tell me what is your input ?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="index.php" id="myform">
Enter your suburb name and postcode: 
<input type="text" name="search" id="txtSearch" value=""> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/><br />
</form>

$serchkeys = isset($_POST['search'])? $_POST['search'] : "0000 map map";

Comment: after I have to call function $result = searchFunction($suburbs,$postCode); 
if(!result)

{ $returnedFromUrl = file_get_contents("yoururl/?suburb=".$result["suburbs"]."&po‌​stCode=".$result["po‌​stCode"]); }
else

{ // Search string error }

Comment: Okay now lets try with typing 0000map it will give you suburb as map and post code as 0000

Comment: No mate you will call function like this : 

$result = searchFunction($serchkeys); if( $result ){ //success validation }else{ //error }

Comment: Thanks I changed $result = searchFunction($serchkeys); Which one is correct if($result) or if(!$result)?

Comment: if( $result ) means searchFunction returned array so you should use it for successful operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can search on the first 2 examples then for any input just remove whitespace

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

and lowercase the input

```
$string = strtolower($string);
```

It would handle other edge cases too.

Comment: Can I use that way $suburbs = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/','/\s+/','', $suburbsname); ?